# Error with ar() function in R - MLE only implemented for univariate series

Tags: r

I am getting an error when I try to use the AR function in R. Here is my code:

```
ord = ar(m2, method = "mle")
```

the `m2` vector is 186 x 1 and contains prices.

The error I get is `"MLE only implemented for univariate series"`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a vector, instead of a matrix, I think:

```
ar(m2[,1], method = "mle")
```